# Getting error while executing and calabash program

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

I am getting this error:

> D:>calabash-android run d:\Android\Apk_Files\EriBank.apk
>   C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs':
>   Could not find 'cucumber' (~> 1.3.17) - did find: [cucumber-2.0.0]
>   (Gem::LoadError)
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in`block n
>   activate_dependencies'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in`activa
>   e_dependencies'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1266:in `activa e'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:54:in`ge '
>           from C:/Ruby21/bin/calabash-android:22:in `'

Comment: Can you share corresponding code snippet?

Comment: looks like you have the wrong version of cucumber

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining about your version of cucumber gem, you should downgrade it to 1.3.17 or 1.3.19.

To downgrade do

```
gem uninstall cucumber
gem install cucumber -v 1.3.19
```